# Why is Shavuos one day and not seven?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, shavuos

Why is Shavuos just one day, instead of a full week?

Of the three Regalim (Pesach, Shavuos, and Sukkos), Shavuos is the only one which isn’t seven days long. Furthermore, in regards to bringing the Karban Chagigah, it *is* treated as a full week, in the sense that if someone didn’t bring it on Shavuos, he has another six days to bring it ([Chagigah 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah_17a.5)). However, only the first day is actually Yom Tov; the remainder of the week has no extra sanctity.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28709/. However, that asks why Shavuos isn’t next to Pesach, like Shmini Atzeres is to Sukkos, rather than why Shavuos is only one day to begin with.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't ask that, but rather why the other holidays are groups (7 days of Pesach, 8 of Sukkot/ShA) while Shavuot is just 1. IIUC

Comment: Note Shmini Atzeret is also on 1 day long, and so is each of Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur. That's 4 one-day holidays and 2 seven-day

Comment: @Double AA but of the shalosh regalim, Shavuos is the only one that is one day and not connected to another chag.

Comment: @LoAni it's also the _only_ day in Sivan with full Hallel. (You can make anything unique if you limit your scope sufficiently, but that doesn't make such a status interesting or question-worthy.)

Comment: @Double AA but limiting the scope to shalosh regalim seems reasonable enough to me, and seemingly to the Op as well.